# SQL doesn't work in SQL Server, fine in Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server

This statement works in Oracle but not in SQL Server - what am I missing?

```
update table1 d set client_ip           = null
                   ,account_open        = null
                   ,sales_rev           = null
where not exists (select 'submitted' 
                  from    table2 e 
                  where   d.application_id = e.application_id
                  and     e.event          = 'XXX');
```

EDIT: [Code: 102, SQL State: 42000]  Incorrect syntax near 'd'.

Comment: "*doesn't work*" is not a problem description.

Comment: What happens in SQL Server? DO you get an error? The wrong results?

Comment: is submitted a column name?

Comment: Is that the whole error message? No line number or other context?

Comment: @scsimon Actually inside a not exists clause, you can select any constant, or a valid column name, or *,  it won't change the results.  i often use SELECT 42, cause, you know, that's the answer!

Comment: good catch @user1443098 i read `not in` in my head

Comment: `UPDATE d SET ... FROM table1 d WHERE NOT EXISTS....` Just need a from clause in SQL Server

Answer (score -2):

Oracle and  SQL Servers are not compatible at all. The best is use for example [this site](http://www.sqlines.com/online) for converting sql code

Comment: Thanks but that site makes no changes, SQL on left (oracle) same as right (sql server)

Comment: Post the error message or description of what it is that doesn't work.

Comment: *Not compatible at all* is a massive overstatement.  There are surely more similarities than differences.

Comment: @user1443098 if think you shouldnt you that alias 'd' at ```update table1 d ```. I think this is a problem. Make also query that works on join

Comment: thanks for the warm welcome from some of you...i will never reach voting status here :(. So this works; update d set d.client_ip           = null
    ,d.account_open = null
    ,d.sales_rev    = null
    from table1 d
    where not exists (select 'submitted' 
    from    table2 e 
                  where   d.application_id = e.application_id
                  and       e.event_type_cd  = 'xxx');